# Combining ggplot2 with base plots in R: Looks and Syntax

Tags: r, ggplot2

The ggplot* differ from base R plots in two dimensions: (1) they have many syntax and feature differences *and* (2) they look differents.

For longer papers, I would often want to use different packages for different graphs, if only because answers on stack overflow often provide one but not the other solution.  The problem is that the looks are too incongruent.

Is there a setting feature that makes ggplot* graphs look a lot more like base plots, or vice-versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to use `theme_base` from `ggthemes` when I want my plots to look like base `R` plots:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
        geom_point() +
        theme_base()
```

[image]